# Number of function evaluation is accumulating with each run

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate the number of function evaluation from a matlab code. The problem is, each time I run the code, it seems the NFE keeps increasing (accumulating). How can I stop this so that that when I switch to different function expression, the NFE will be distinct, if possible. The body of my function is like this

```
function y = g(x,n)
global gcount
if isempty(gcount)
 gcount = 0;
end
if nargin == 0  % Reply counter and reset it
  y = gcount;
  gcount = 0;
  return;
end
gcount = gcount + 1;
%----------------------- problem 6 -------------------------%
% c = 1:n;
% yy = 2*sum(x(c))+1/50*c*x(c);
% y = yy';
%----------------------- problem 8 -------------------------%
c = 1:n;
yy = 2*c*(x(c)).^2+1/50*sum(x(c));
y = yy';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you declare `gcount` to be `global` anywhere else in your code, or have you done this in the command window before running it? If you declare a global variable in the base workspace **before** you declare it as global in a function definition, the function will access the variable in the base workspace, so the value will persist between runs.

If you want your `gcount` variable to start counting from 0 each time you run your code, the easiest way would be to reset it to 0 or `clear` it at the beginning of your top level script.

However if what you actually want to know is how many times a function was called, a far better way of doing it is to use MATLAB's [profiler](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html). The Profile Summary Report shows this information for all functions in your code. If you need to access the results programatically, you can use [`profile`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) to get the data for an individual function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The second paragraph of your response really answered my question. I have two variables declared as global at the beginning of my code. One is fcount (for number of test function evaluation), the other is gcount (for number of gradient evaluation). After running the code a number of times after setting the global variables to zero as instructed, I got the desired outputs. However, I noticed the difference of 1 between the values of fcount and gcount. This happens for all my tested functions. Please is there anytime I am missing out.